# Loop through for each a set number of times without an array in Mule

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm using Mule 4 and Anypoint Studio 7.3

I want to use a for each statement which will call a HTTP request a fixed number of times.  Can I set the for each to loop through a set number of times e.g. 4 times when the payload is not an array?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using the expression `#[0 to 9]` for example to iterate 10 times

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="919f04d5-f608-485a-a33b-6a6c2851b6b1" collection="#[0 to 9]">
  <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="ed114a04-f0ae-4ab2-8b86-a710ec1cbb8f" />
</foreach>
```